# Does a vector function always output a position vector?

Tags: calculus, vectors

My calculus 3 textbook states that the output of a vector function is a vector, but the diagrams presented all show a vector function outputting a set of position vectors that trace a curve in space.

I'm wondering if vector functions only output position vectors or can it output any vector not at the origin? Is it more convenient to have it typically output a position vector?

Comment: A vector not situated at the origin is equal to one that is by a parallel translation, so there's no difference.  This is about convenience.

Comment: @Randall Ah I see thank you!

Comment: Position vectors are useful for building intuition but they're optional. I would also point out that the zero vector is a vector, so the output vector can be $0$.